# Combine rdd string lines without reduce

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I retrieve data from text file using rdd in spark, it looks like that the retrieved lines are seprated from each other.

What i want is that the rdd combines them and treat them as if I have parallelized a single string.

e.g: from rddcontent:

```
sc.TextFile("sample.txt") // content: List("abc", \n "def")
```

To:

```
sc.parallelize("abcdef") // content: "abcdef"
```

This should be done because the whole data is too big to fit in memory with reduce but still needs to be processed as a whole(In parallel of course but without the line seperations)

Comment: You can try `.flatMap(identity)` it will be `RDD[Char]`

Comment: Or it would be nice if you supplied some example, how are you intended to use such parallelized string

Comment: To repartition it using .sliding() . Also i guess the flat map actually converts it to List( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"). But ill give it a try

Comment: No. It'll just use char iterator for each string when it'll come to actual job.